# How to install Python module on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-module

I just wrote a function on Python. Then, I wanted to make it module and install on my Ubuntu 11.04. Here is what I did.

1. Created setup.py along with function.py file.
2. Built distribution file using $Python2.7 setup.py sdist
3. Then installed it $Python2.7 setup.py install

All was going fine. But, later I wanted to use the module importing it on my code.
I got import error: ImportError: No module named '-------'

PS. I searched over google and didn't find particular answer. Detailed answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to install to global python?. Then you need root permission for "$Python2.7 setup.py install"

Comment: I am trying to install on my local machine.

Comment: But do you have write permission to its lib?. Try "$which python2.7". If that shows /usr/bin/python2.7, you might need root access.

Comment: Are you sure the `setup.py install` command didn't error?  You WILL need to call `sudo` for it to write the compiled modules to the python library directory in Ubuntu.

Comment: Last line message is this: Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nester-1.0.0.egg-info

Comment: "Last line message is this".  That's not 'site-packages'.  Your code needs to be installed in site-packages.  Please include the **actual** log with the **actual** commands and **actual** output in your question.

Comment: OK. Let me some time. I am gonna add detailed question.

Comment: I have chosen the answer. It was problem related to root user. Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu use dist-packages, not site-packages (long story).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Most installation requires:

`sudo python setup.py install`

Otherwise, you won't be able to write to the installation directories.

I'm pretty sure that (unless you were root), you got an error when you did

`python2.7 setup.py install`

Answer (score 3):

I could not install any modules or eggs until I used the package manager to install (for my version) python2.6-dev

```
 sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev
```

After that, I was able to run the setup.py file that was included in the downloaded and unpacked module without gcc errors. I assume python2.6-dev is the "development package".